# Links do not stay inline in list items

Tags: css

I have this list, without using `<ul>`:

```
<li>some text before <a href="url1">item 1</a> some text after</li>
<li>some text before <a href="url2">item 2</a> some text after</li>
<li>some text before <a href="url3">item 3</a> some text after</li>
<li>some text before <a href="url4">item 4</a> some text after</li>
<li>some text before <a href="url5">item 5</a> some text after</li>
```

With this CSS I try to keep the link in place but onClick it keeps moving a line down.

```
#myDiv li a { 
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: #0080BC; 
    outline: none; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Can anyone help me with the right way to get this done?
It must me clear CSS but I can't seem to get it done.

Comment: Is this all of your CSS?

Comment: Eh, no... there are some 2000 more lines in it :-) But I thought the #-id would make it an object on itself.

Comment: Well, without that CSS, it's hard to see what part of it is affecting those elements.

Comment: Provide a demo of the problem in action (see: http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

#### *I have this list, without using* `<ul>`

A set of list items without `<ul>` is invalid in HTML. Since you have a CSS with a `#myDiv`, you can enclose the whole stuff inside `<ul id="#myDiv">` this way, as the CSS is fine:

```
<ul id="#myDiv">
    <li>some text before <a href="url1">item 1</a> some text after</li>
    <li>some text before <a href="url2">item 2</a> some text after</li>
    <li>some text before <a href="url3">item 3</a> some text after</li>
    <li>some text before <a href="url4">item 4</a> some text after</li>
    <li>some text before <a href="url5">item 5</a> some text after</li>
</ul>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwpem/

The list items are fine. But if you feel that the list items to be inline, then you need to add this CSS:

```css
#myDiv li {display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen, but the problem still remains.

Comment: What is the problem now? Can you post some screenshot?